# how to use @Autowired in the test methods

Tags: java, spring, junit, dependency-injection, autowired

I am not able to use Spring's @Autowired annotations in the test methods.I am using JUnit for testing. @Autowiring works for normal classes in the beans but it does not work with the test methods. As I read in the forums, I have to implement spring-test in the pom.xml. I am still not able to auto wire and inject dependency of my service bean . Could you please help me to use dependency injection in the test class as I use dependency injection in my source classes.

Regards
Alper

Comment: You need to setup the context for tests in a similar way you do when running the app. There's a lot of info on http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/testing.html but in short, you should use @ContextConfiguration and @RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class). Also see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2862888/how-to-create-testcontext-for-spring-test Sorry I don't have time for a full answer. Btw, I didn't downvote you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you are writing unit tests a recommend you use `@Mock` and `@InjectMocks`.

You can annotate your test classes to run with `MockitoJUnitRunner`

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class TestClass{
  @Mock
  private MockedClass;
  @InjectMocks
  private TestedClass;
}
```

But if you really want test all the flow and need to inject classes, you can `@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)` and `@Autowired` your classes.

---

Update:

Try adding this dependency on your spring boot application (don't need to add the version) to use `SpringJUnit4ClassRunner`:

```
groupId: org.springframework.boot 
artifactId: spring-boot-starter-test 
scope: test 
version: 1.4.4
```

Comment: Hello pedroso. I come across with java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/transaction/TransactionDefinition when I added @RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class).

Comment: Try add this dependency on your spring boot application (dont need to add the version):
    groupId: org.springframework.boot
    artifactId: spring-boot-starter-test
    scope: test
    version: 1.4.4